# Calling another method from Modelclass to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, models, controllers

I would like to call a method from my "ShoppingCart" model class to my HomeController. If Action "Complete" is executed, I want the method "EmptyCart" to happen. Is there a good way to do this?

This is the modelclass:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    FotobutikkJLCDbContext db = new FotobutikkJLCDbContext();

    string ShoppingCartId { get; set; } 

    public void EmptyCart()
    {
     var cartItems = db.Carts.Where(cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId);

     foreach (var cartItem in cartItems)
        {
            db.Carts.Remove(cartItem);
        }

        // Save changes
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And this is the ActionResult:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Complete()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Complete";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model needs to be passed back to the controller for the controller to know about it, then just call `EmptyCart()`.

```
public ActionResult Complete(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Complete";
    shoppingCart.EmptyCart();

    return View();
}
```